# Understanding the nature of Flutter constraints through a specific example

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-constraint

#### Prelude

I'm familiar with the [dictum](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints)

> "*Constraints go down. Sizes go up. Parent sets position.*'

What I'd like to understand is how "constraints" are defined. Is it just a range ("*height must be between 30 and infinity*"), or is there something more elaborate? Surely I can find the answer from reading Flutter's code, but I'm not yet at that stage.

A **concrete answer** addressing a very specific example is much more helpful than hand-waving.
Hence in an effort to avoid vague answers, please address the following **concrete** example.

#### Question

Why does uncommenting the commented-out line trigger an error?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Text('Hello),
            Text('World),
        ]),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Text('How),
            Text('are you?),
        ]),
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

#### Clarification

The following is another way of asking the question.

In the three part:

- "*Constraints go down.*"
- "*Sizes go up.*"
- "*Parent sets position.*"

it's clear what "*size*" is. It is the `Size` [class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Size-class.html).

It's also clear what "*position*" is. There is also a [class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Offset-class.html) for that (`Offset`).

1. Is [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/Constraints-class.html) the class that captures a "*constraint*"? Is it visible from the programmer side?
2. How does the instance of that class change when we uncomment the commented-out line (thereby triggering the error)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constraints for a widget are defined by 4 `doubles`, min and max width, min and max height, with infinity as a possible value.

Now on your question, setting `CrossAxisAlignment` to `Stretch`, causes the constraints passed to the children to be `tight` in the cross axis.

A `tight` constraint in flutter is when, the parent offers to its child only ONE size, for its width and its height, so the min and max width will be equal, same goes for the min and max height.
On the other hand, a `loose` constraint only sets the max width and the max height, but the child can be as small as it wants.

When the parent gives a constraint, that is `loose` and `infinite` on a specific axis, the child must give back a `size` for that axis that is **NOT** `infinite`, otherwise Flutter will throw `BoxConstraints forces an infinite height`.

For example, if you have a `Column`, that gives infinite height to its child `ListView`, the `ListView`, if not wrapped by a specific widget, will throw, as it's trying to give back an infinite height to the parent,
in that case, you can either wrap the `ListView` with an `Expanded` widget, or a `SizedBox`.

In your example, this is what is happening:
Your `Column` widget, is giving the following height constraints to its 2 children (the 2 `Rows`)

- min height : 0, max heigth: infinity.

These are `loose` constraints, so the children can take as much size as they need.
And each of those `Rows` then, passes the same constraints to its children (the 2 `Text` widgets), and again, the constraints are the same and loose,
so the Text widgets can be as tall as they want.

As soon as you set the `CrossAxisAlignment` to `Stretch`, the constraints that the `Row` is passing down are tight, this means that when the parent `Column`, asks the child `Row` that has `Stretch`, what size it wants to be,
the `Row` will answer with `infinite` (always referring to the height), and this will throw the error, as said before, if the constraint set by the parent is already `infinite`, the size the child wants cannot be `infinite` as well, on that axis.

So to solve this, when a child is setting a `tight` constraint for its children, and the parent of that child is giving `infinite` constraint on a specific axis,
the child **MUST** be either wrapped in a `Flex` widget (`Expanded`, `Flexible`) or it must have a `finite` size (e.g wrapping it with a `SizedBox`).
So for your example, if you wrap your `Stretch` Row, in either a `Flexible` or `Expanded` widget, your error will go away:

```
 return Column(
  children: [
    Flexible(      /// this fixes your issue
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Text('Hello'),
          Text('World'),
      ]),
    ),
    Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Text('How'),
        Text('are you?'),
    ]),
  ]
);
```

To sum up, if a parent Widget gives, on a specific axis, `infinite` contraint, then the child, cannot ask to have its size, on that specific axis, `infinite` as well, because, if there are multiple children, the following one won't have any space left to size themselves.
In this case, the child **MUST** be either wrapped with a `sizing` widget, or with a `flex` widget.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of the row: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html , the first step of the render is `Layout each child a null or zero flex factor (e.g., those that are not Expanded) with unbounded horizontal constraints and the incoming vertical constraints. If the crossAxisAlignment is CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, instead use tight vertical constraints that match the incoming max height.`

And the fourth step: `The height of the Row is the maximum height of the children (which will always satisfy the incoming vertical constraints).`

Since you're not specifing any container or "wrapper", Flutter doesn't know what height ot put on the row when you're stretching the crossAxis.

In your example:

Let's say you wrap the first wor in a Container with 400 height and the second text also inside a Container to see what's happening when stretching to minimun and maximun possible height:

```
Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      height: 400,
      child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Text('Hello'),
            Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              child: Text(
                'World',
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: 40,
              height: 20,
              color: Colors.blue,
            )
          ]),
    )
```

Result:

[image]

But if you use another variation: center, start, end, the containers would wrap to its minimum:

```
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center:
```

[image]

```
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start:
```

[image]

```
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end:
```

[image]